# What zombie game is this PvP comic referencing?

Tags: game-identification

I'm very curious: what game are they playing in [today's (Jan 02, 2013) *PvP* comic](http://pvponline.com/comic/2013/01/02/let-the-bodies-hit-the-floor)?

[image: PvP for 2013-01-02]

Answer (score 16):

This is a reference to [*ZombiU*](http://zombiu.ubi.com/zombi/en-us/home/index.aspx/), a game for the WiiU.  The game features permadeath, and you can go back and raid your previous lives' corpses for what you were carrying at the time.  You can also see the large WiiU gamepad in Francis' hands in the last panel.  The [Queen's Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen's_Guard) soldier in the third panel is also a character featured prominently in the game's promotional art.